# Find and display only values that are the same in sql

Tags: sql

I am doing a query based on a swimming event.  There are unique event codes, as well as unique swimmer codes, and their placing.  I am currently having a problem, as I want to display only swimmers that have TIED in the same event (EG I want to display only the swimmers that tied in the 100m relay).

Is there some syntax which does that?

I was doing something similar to this

```
SELECT Swimmers, Eventid, Place
FROM Results
WHERE Place=Place
AND Eventid=Eventid
```

But that includes even swimmers that did not tie.

Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT Swimmers, 
       Eventid, 
       Place
FROM  Results a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT EventID, Place ,COUNT(Place) totalPlace
            FROM Results
            GROUP BY EventID, Place
            HAVING COUNT(Place) > 1
        ) b ON a.eventID = b.EventID AND
                a.Place = b.Place
-- WHERE -- add extra conditions here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
    SELECT Swimmers, EventId, Place
    FROM Results r JOIN
      (SELECT EventId, Place
       FROM Results
       GROUP BY EventId, Place
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t ON (r.EventId = t.EventId AND r.Place = t.Place)
```